# Weight Paint not working on one character

Tags: armature, vertices, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I've assigned armatures and weight painted several characters in this file and now it's not working for this one character. Everytime i try to weight paint it i see the verticies like in edit mode and can't draw or subtract on any parts of the mesh. does anyone know what is happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually simple why it doesn't work, no need to worry, you just somehow pressed or activated this button:

[image]

This function allows you to select only vertices you want and you will be able to draw weights only for those vertices that are selected. It's basically a mask function for weight painting.

Turn it off by clicking it and it should let you draw again (it is also the reason why you see vertices)

Comment: ooh haha :') thank you so much!